# C finding the last element of the list passed as a argument

Tags: c, list

I have a global list

```
typedef struct center {
  char center_name[100];
  char hostname[100];
  int port;

  struct center *next_center;
} center;
```

So when i start:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  center *head = null;
  parse(argv, &head);
}
```

where parse:

```
 void parser (char** argv, center **head) {
   //read a file amd add the elements to a newCenter
   addToCenterList(newcenter, head);
 }
```

where addToCenterList:

```
void addToCenterList(center *newcenter, center **head) {
  center *newNode = malloc(sizeof(center));
  strcpy(newNode->center_name, newcenter->center_name);                
  strcpy(newNode->hostname, newcenter->hostname);
  newNode->port = newcenter->port;
  newcenter->next_center = NULL;    

  if (*head == NULL)       
    *head = newNode; 
  else {
    //problem starts here, it never adds after the first element
    center **iterator; 
    center ite; 
    iterator = head; 
    ite = **iterator;

    while(1){
      if(ite.next_center == NULL){
        *ite.next_center = *newNode; 
        break; 
      }                  
    }
}
```

My problem starts with the else:
I am passing the address of the head of the list.
So I know i need a variable that allows to move through the list. 
I have tried many things and none work. 
I had in mind: iterate through the list and store the address of each "node" in some variable, and if the content of that address (the node!) its the next_center is == NULL then i would stop looking since that is the last element.
And afterward i would just assign that next_center address a new content.

Thats what i am trying to do. I dont know how to make it work....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
void addToCenterList(center *newcenter, center **head) {
  center *newNode ;

  while  (*head )       { head = &(*head)->next_center;  }

  *head = newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNod);
  strcpy(newNode->center_name, newcenter->center_name);
  strcpy(newNode->hostname, newcenter->hostname);
  newNode->port = newcenter->port;
  /* Note the next line:
   ** the OP assigned not to newNode, but to newcenter,
   ** which appears to be
   ** "read-only" source data element
   */
  newNode->next_center = NULL; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the asterisks in the last lines of addToCenterList and see what happens.

```
item *k = &head;
while (*k != NULL)
    k = &((*k)->next);
item e = calloc(1, sizeof(struct element));
if (!e) {// calloc didn't work
    // error handling
}
e->value = value;
*k = e;
```

Notice that `item` is of type pointer:

```
struct element {
    int value;
    struct element * next;
};

typedef struct element * item;
```

You would have to adjust it for your implementation (add some asterisks there and remove some here).

And the asterisks statement was because it causes errors afaik: You can't assign whole `structs`, that's why you should do it with pointers instead.

Comment: it does nothing when i print the list in main. It just prints the first element. nothing else

Comment: I found a method of iterating through a linked list, implemented by me:

`item *k = &head;
 while (*k) k = &((*k)->next);`
I think your else case in your `while(1)` is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1){
     if(ite.next_center == NULL){
         *ite.next_center = *newNode; 
         break; 
     }                   
}
```

This loop considers what to do if your iterator is the last element, but not what to do if it isnt. You need to add a `else { ite = ite->next;}` or something to that effect, so that you keep iterating through the list until you find the end.

The second problem, perhaps more key, is that you are modifying a copy of the list.

```
center ite; 
...
ite = **iterator;
```

This creates a copy of the list element. You then assign to this copy, and the copy is destroyed at the end of the block.

Fix that with

```
center *ite; 
...
ite = *iterator;
```

This will insert the second element (fix syntax in the while(1) loop) and then inserting the third element will cause a infinite loop due to the first mentioned issue.

Comment: i know that, but it should add a second element, which it does not. So the problem stays the same...

Comment: @Alessandroempire please see my edit, there is a second problem